# Two select boxes with one function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have here two select boxes. The process is like this http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp. What I need to display only the value between the two select boxes. How I can do that in one function? Any help will appreciate.

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    var $txtHint = $('#txtHint');
    if (str=="") {
        $txtHint.html('');
        return;
    }
    $txtHint.load('ajax.php?q='+str)    
}
</script>

<select name="customers" id="customers" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a customer:</option>
<option value="ALFKI">Alfreds Futterkiste</option>
<option value="NORTS ">North/South</option>
<option value="WOLZA">Wolski Zajazd</option>
</select>

<select name="city" class="city">
<option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand... you mean you want both `<select>` elements to use the same function when they change? Can you please clarify this sentence: "What I need to display only the value between the two select boxes."

Comment: @HamzaKubba Pardon for unclear question. Yah I need both elements use the same function when change.

Comment: Okay, will add generic code to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

First, take the function that you're calling inside `change()`, and declare it separately. Then, call `.change()` on that function twice.

E.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var myChangeFunction = function() {
        var city = $(".city").val();
        var customer = $("#customer").val();

        if (city && customer) {
            // do something only if both are set
        }
    };

    $(".city").change(myChangeFunction);
    $("#customer").change(myChangeFunction);

});
```

Comment: not this. The above function that displays the information in HTML table. onchange="showUser(this.value)"

Comment: So change the `#customers` in my code to `'.country'` or whatever... I don't see any other `<select>` elements in your code.

Comment: And I'm not trying to fix all your code... you said you wanted to make two elements call the same function with onchange... that's how you do it...

Comment: element customer has onchange="showUser(this.value)" function that display database information. What I need to do is add that function in element city. So when I select in both element only the value selected will display the selected information.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand you... I updated my answer with what I understood you want, but your explanations are quite vague.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what you need.
You need both selects to call the same function onchange.
That function will get some info, and load it. You need it to load it in different places regarding which was the select that changed.
If that's what you need, check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hige/4878B/

Remember to uncomment the .load() line, and delete the `console.log()` one.

Hope it helps!